# make a class variable become an instance variable?

Tags: python, class

I try to create a `class_variable` in `my_class`, then I change the value of `class_variable` by a `class instance`. After the change, does the `class_variable` is still belong to a `class variable`, or belong to an `instance variable`? Here is my code:

```
class my_class: 
    class_variable = 'belong to class'

my_instance                = my_class()
print(my_instance.class_variable)
my_instance.class_variable = 'belong to instance'
print(my_instance.class_variable)

# return 
>>>> belong to class
>>>> belong to instance
```

Comment: These are covered in any tutorial on classes and instances.  Please refer to that research before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_class` is a class.

`my_class.class_variable` is a class variable.

`my_instance` is a global variable whose value is an *instance* of `my_class`.

`class_var_class` is a global variable whose value is the same as that of `my_class.class_variable`.  It is not itself a class variable.

After you reassign `my_instance.class_variable`, it creates a new instance variable that *shadows* the class variable.  (In general, you don't want to do this!  Give your instance variables and class variables different names, and define all your instance variables in your class's `__init__` method rather than sticking them on later.)

`class_var_instance` is a global variable which has the same value as the one you just assigned to `my_instance.class_variable`.

Comment: that's a clear explanation, I get it and thanks.

Comment: maybe one more further question, after I reassign value to 'my_instance.class_variable', if I call it again (by 'my_instance.class_variable'), it will give me "'belong to instance'", so does it mean I change the 'class variable', or does it mean this become an 'instance variable'? While I know for other instances, if I call the class variable from them, they are still ''belong to class'.

Comment: You've added an instance variable with the same name as the class variable -- that's what I meant by "shadowing".  The class variable still exists, but now `my_instance.class_variable` will reference the instance variable instead.  This is a confusing situation which is why I advise not doing that.  :)

Comment: see: https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/a-note-on-python-class-attributes.html

Comment: I just read the link and understand it, so I was just making a new instance variable which had the same name with class variable, I get it, thank.